# How do I track changes to my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am have text that when you click it, the background-color turns green, and if you click it again it turns red and then one more click it turns back to white. I have successfully linked my javascript to change the color to green but I can't figure out how to track the changes to javascript to recognize that it is green, and then to change it to red.

What I have is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_color($id){

    var link = document.getElementById('link-'+$id);

    var color = link.style.backgroundColor;
    if (color == "green"){
    link.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }if (color == "red"){
    link.style.backgroundColor="white";
    }if (color == "white"){
    link.style.backgroundColor="green";
    }else{
    link.style.backgroundColor="green";
    }

}

</script>
```

When I run the program it is only using the else statement I believe.  How can I track the current backgroundColor in order to activate the above if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the color is green, you set it to red. Then the next condition checks for red (which is now true) and updates the color again.

Consider using a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement instead of the `if`/`else` statements.

Comment: And if you use `switch`, make sure you've got `break` at the end of each case unless you really do want fall-through!

Comment: Genius! Worked and also made another part of my code more efficient, thank you!!

Comment: And icktoofay, you really saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check multiple conditions but *only run one of them*, you need to use `else if` for all conditions after the first one:

```
if (color == "green"){
    link.style.backgroundColor="red";
}else if (color == "red"){
    link.style.backgroundColor="white";
}else if (color == "white"){
    link.style.backgroundColor="green";
}else{
    link.style.backgroundColor="green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `if..else if..else` between your `if`'s or use a `switch-case` instead:

```
var color = link.style.backgroundColor;
var newColor = "green";
switch (color) {
    case "green":
    {
        newColor="red";
        break;
    }

    case "red":
    {
        newColor="white";
        break;
    }

    case "white":
    {
        newColor = "green";
        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        break;
    }
}

link.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
```